# Groovy check for unused imports

Tags: java, maven, groovy, static-analysis, checkstyle

I want to fail my build if there are unused imports, I tried using the Checkstyle Plugin but it doesn't work. Is there any other way/plugin that can help me check for unused imports in Groovy files.

My pom file looks like

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
            <artifactId>buildtools</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Have you tried codenarc?

Answer (score 0):

Try CodeNarc, it has an UnusedImport rule: http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-imports.html